# detect when pressing the deleted key using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a calculator program using jquery program. In the following code I need to capture the delete key.

```
$("body").on("keydown",function(evt) {

  var ChCod = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        strvalue=String.fromCharCode(ChCod);

  if (ChCod > 31 && (ChCod < 48 || ChCod > 57) && (ChCod!=43) && (ChCod!=45) && (ChCod!=42) && (ChCod!=47) && (ChCod!=61) && (ChCod!=13) && (ChCod!=46)) {

    return false;
  }
  else
  {
        if(ChCod==43 || ChCod==45 || ChCod==42 || ChCod==47 || ChCod==61 || ChCod==13|| ChCod==46)
        {
            if(ChCod==46)
                Dot();
            else if(strvalue=='=' || ChCod==13)
                Calculate();
            else    
                Operate(strvalue);
        }
        else                
            AddDigit(strvalue);

        return false;
  }

});
```

If I am using keydown event, It will not correctly trigger the number. (eg: when I pressing the '1' it return 'a')

Comment: Why can't you use both `keypress` and `keydown`/`keyup`? It's like "I can't use forks, they don't work for soups".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("body").on("keyup",function(evt) {
```

Use key up event then you will get correct char value